# TogglerBar Problem

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

Is it possible to save information from a toggler bar to a variable when a button is clicked?

Example:

I have a toggler bar with its buttons numbered, say 1–4. When I press on a the button showing 1, I would like to have 1 saved to variable `x`. When I press the button showing 2 is pressed, I would like 2 saved to variable `y`. And so on.

Comment: Does using the second argument of `Dynamic` work for you? E.g. `TogglerBar[Dynamic[x,caching_function],choices]`? The `caching_function` could just set the value passed to a variable, as you wanted.

Answer (score 7):

I think this does what you want. `a` is the control variable and `x`, `y`, and `z` are controlled by the togglers.

```
TogglerBar[
  Dynamic[a, (a = #; Clear[x, y, z]; ReleaseHold[#]) &],
  {Hold[x = 1] -> 1, Hold[y = 2] -> 2, Hold[z = 3] -> 3}
]

Dynamic[{x, y, z}]
```

[image]

If that does what you want here is a utility function to make using it easier.

```
SetAttributes[myToggles, HoldFirst]

myToggles[var_, val_] := myToggles[var, val, val]

myToggles[{var__Symbol}, val : {__}, lbl : {__}] :=
  Module[{a},
    TogglerBar[
      Dynamic[a, (a = #; Clear[var]; ReleaseHold[#]) &], 
      MapThread[
        Function[, Hold[# = #2] -> #3, HoldAll],
        Unevaluated @ {{var}, val, lbl}
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Examples:

```
myToggles[{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}]
Dynamic[{a, b c}]

myToggles[{m, n, o}, {1, 2, 3}, {"one", "two", "three"}]
Dynamic[{m, n, o}]
```

Comment: This is marvelous code, whether it does what the OP wants or not.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you. :-)

Comment: This is perfect,  this is exactly what I needed . Thank you very much!!

Comment: @JoshuaHernandez I am glad I could help. :-)  Since this fully meets your needs please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use an indexed variable to track the buttons pressed on the bar, fairly simple code will work.

```
Clear[bar, b]
bF = (bar = #; Clear[b]; Evaluate[b /@ #] = #) &;
With[{nBtns = 5},
  Column[
    {TogglerBar[Dynamic[bar, bF], Range[nBtns]],
     Dynamic[b /@ Range[nBtns]]}]]
```

[image: bar]